# Comparar promedios - SQL

Tags: mysql, sql, base-de-datos, postgresql

¿Cómo puedo comparar un promedio total de un campo con el promedio de una *tupla* que tiene una determinada condición?

Mi idea era hacer un `avg(sum(nombre_campo))` para determinar el promedio total, pero *SQL* no me deja anidar funciones agregadas.

Comment: Incluso si te dejara, hacer `AVG(SUM(campo))` no sería lo adecuado: el resultado de `SUM` es un valor único, por lo que el `AVG` del `SUM` sería el mismo valor del `SUM` (porque sólo hay uno). ¿Podrías poner un ejemplo de la tabla y los valores que tienes, y qué es lo que quieres sumar y de qué quieres hacer el promedio? Tal y como está ahora no termina de quedar claro. Lee [ask] y cómo crear un [mcve] para más información. Y quizás un enlace a SQLFiddle (o similar) sería de ayuda para ver el problema mejor. Saludos.

Comment: Haz intentado hacer una operación de sub-proyección, por ejemplo: SELECT aveg(x) from ( Select sum(field) x table )...

Comment: Termine haciendo un having avg(campo) > (select avg(campo) from tabla) y funciono de 10 :). Gracias!